# when UISegmentcontrol item changing, why it will hide customBadge in IOS 5?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I have added custom Badge on UISegmentControl. In `Xcode 4.0.2 SDK 4.3` its working fine. But in `Xcode 4.2 SDK 5.0` custom badge is not shown when another item is selected. I dont know why this happens? I'm using following code for `IOS 4.3 Xcode 4.0.2`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    super.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wallpaper.png"]];
    NSLog(@"Root View Loaded");

    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             @"Home",@"Surveys",@"Results",@"Create",@"Settings",
                                             nil]];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 40);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    segmentedControl.momentary = NO;
    segmentedControl.highlighted = YES;

    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

    UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

    NSArray *segmentBarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                segmentBarItem,nil];

    [[self appDelegate] setSegmentedControl:segmentedControl];
    [[self appDelegate] setSegmentBarArray:segmentBarArray];

    [self setToolbarItems:[[self appDelegate] segmentBarArray] animated:NO];

    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    int surveycount = [[self appDelegate] getUnreadSurveyCount];
    surveyCountBadge = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",surveycount]];
    [surveyCountBadge setFrame:CGRectMake(105, -10, surveyCountBadge.frame.size.width, surveyCountBadge.frame.size.height)];

    [segmentedControl addSubview:surveyCountBadge];    
    if (surveycount == 0) {
        [surveyCountBadge setHidden:YES];
    }else{
        [surveyCountBadge setHidden:NO];
    }
}
-(void)segmentAction:(id) sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    NSLog(@"selected index is %d",segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);

    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex  ==1){
        surveyForMeViewController = [[SurveyForMeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SurveyForMeView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:surveyForMeViewController animated:YES];

    } else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex  ==2){
        resultViewController = [[ResultView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:resultViewController animated:YES];

    } else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==3) {
        newSurveyViewController = [[NewSurveyView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewSurveyView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newSurveyViewController animated:YES];

    } else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==4) {
        settingsViewControlle = [[SettingsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsViewControlle animated:YES];
    }


}
```

Any thing else should I mention in this?

Comment: No one can help you unless you post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a subview to a segmentedControl. As you don't know how the system redraws the control when another item is selected, you cannot say if your view will be removed or not. Let the control, button or segmentedControl do its work and if you want to add a badge, add it as a subview of its parent.

```
[surveyCountBadge setFrame:CGRectMake(105.0f+segmentedControl.frame.origin.x,
   -10.0f+sementedControl.frame.origin.y, surveyCountBadge.frame.size.width, 
    surveyCountBadge.frame.size.height)];

[[segmentedControl superView] addSubview: surveyCountBadge];
```

Comment: Of course. badge is no part of the control so you have to hide it separately.

Comment: OK but when hide and then show then custom Badge again blur. Again what should i do?

Comment: @Siten: Blur? What do you mean with blur?